# Is there a clear and reliable methodology for workloads profiling/modeling?

Tags: performance, optimization, profiling, modeling, profiler

I want to evaluate the hardware resource requirements of a certain workload from the following aspects:

1. **Hyper-threading** friendliness
2. Sensitivity to **memory latency/memory bandwidth**
3. Sensitivity to **the number of allocated physical cores** (in container-based workloads, the cpu quota remains unchanged, the impact of changing the number of cores in the cpuset)
4. Sensitivity to **pagecache**
5. Sensitivity to **available cache space size**

I would like to ask if there are relevant methodologies, tools or papers for practice in the above aspects?

Comment: I think the question is too broad. Each point can be addressed separately and generally require different approaches. For 2), I would track the imc counters and the memory latency precise counters for example. For 1) it is quite complicated to do it rigorously. A good approach is certainly architecture-dependent. A not-to-bad solution is just to run it and compare results while tracking the source of slowdown with some PMU events. For 3), a strong scaling or weak scaling may be enough.

Comment: IMO, the is no such thing as "available cache space size" at low level. This is an abstract concept and it is hard to evaluate the amount due to many low-level behavior (not to mention it is architecture-dependent and often not completely documented). You can change the cache size but often not really the available one. The cache-line allocation is done by the processor dynamically. In some cases, it can bypass some cache levels, and not even do the allocations in them.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I am considering using Intel's RDT technology to control/monitor the cache capacity used by the program. Do you think this method is okay?